# Porting "SQL" export to T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a 3rd party app that does a database export in to a "SQL format" it is fairly straitforward however it appears to not use T-SQL exactly. When I export it produce something like this

```
INSERT INTO [ExampleDB] ( [IntField] , [DateTimeField] , [VarcharField], [BinaryField])
VALUES
(1 , '2012/04/02 12:25:00:01' , 'Some Text' , X'123456'),
(2 , '0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' , 'B' , NULL),
--(SNIP, it does this for 1000 records)
(999,'0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' , 'Other Text' , null);
(1000 ,'0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' , 'D' , null);

INSERT INTO [ExampleDB] ( [IntField] , [DateTimeField] , [VarcharField] , BinaryField)
VALUES
(1001 , '2012/04/02 12:25:00:01' , 'Trying to break my parser with the next line', null),
(1002 , '0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' , ' ''X''123' , X'deadbeef'),
(1003 , '0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' , 'Did it break it?' , null),
(1004 , '2012/04/02 12:25:00:01' , 'What about this? ''0000/00/00 00:00:00:00'' Will that?' , null),
--(SNIP)
```

The two snags I am running in to are:

- the value of `'0000/00/00 00:00:00:00'` for a date
- the fact that they store binary output as a string prefixed by X

I am thinking I can just do a `Regex.Replace` on it, but I am wondering if there is a easier solution. So far my code to import is

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn))
{
    //snip
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; //Wait forever, bad bad bad, but what else can I do?
    using (var txtRdr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string query = txtRdr.ReadToEnd();
        query = query.Replace(" '0000/00/00 00:00:00:00' ", " NULL ");
        query = Regex.Replace(query, "X'([0-9a-fA-F]+)'", @"0x$1");
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Because the way they list values I know I am tied to SQL2008 or newer but are there any gotchas to the code I wrote to make it parse-able by SQL2008?

When I run it it gets bogged down on the Execute query. The SQL files are 8000 KB in size (but I can adjust it) is there anything I can do to speed it up? Perhaps do some more formatting and turn it in to a bulk insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have had to transfer data between two databases I have found that the quickest way seems to be as follows:

1. Use the unload or equivalent feature to bulk export the source database to a text file.
2. Write software that converts the text file format from the source format to the destination format.
3. Use the bulk import or similar feature to load the text file into the destination database.

Comment: I agree. This question is the #2 step in your process.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, but you said it gets bogged down on the execute, which is why I prefer to use bulk import.

Answer (score 1):

If you have direct access to the source database your safest bet may actually be to query it, and for each record you find insert into the new database. If you accidentally screw up your data before inserting it in some small way, you may not notice until you have a big problem on your hands. If you do the (potentially slower) method of doing an insert for each row, you at least have the security that you're probably not going to bork your data with a misplaced character in a regex. Just a thought.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the source database. The 3rd party program is running on top of the [4D framework](http://www.4d.com/). I am able to call a [SQL Export Database](http://www.4d.com/4d_docstatic/4D/12.3/SQL-EXPORT-DATABASE.301-756573.en.html) and I am trying to load the data in to SQL so I CAN have raw access to the data.

Comment: Is there no way to just to a "Flat File" export or some such instead of having it export unusable nonstandard sql statements?

Comment: All of the Flat file exports that I have attempted does not support exporting the binary fields.